# How to store regex patterns, as regex objects or strings?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

How to store regex patterns, as regex objects or strings?

I have a class X, and I need to store a pattern that will later
be used for matching regular expressions. At this point I simply
have a member called 'patternRegex' as std::string. Would it not
be better if I store an object of type regex? Then the naming
would be just 'pattern' because from the type it will be clear
that it is regex. Are there any tradeoffs I should watch out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Compilation" from string to a regular expression finite state machine is time costly. If you plan to use the regular expressions frequently, eg. in loops, your code will be faster if you keep the regex objects instead of their string representations.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression strings get compiled before use. If you intend to use one regular expression more than once you may like to compile it first by instantiating a `regex` object.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to store them as objects, because constructing a regex from a string invokes parsing the string and building (implementation-defined) parsing structures. So, better create a member field of type `std::regex`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already mentioned that you should store a `std::regex` because it is faster when used multiple times. I think it's worth to point that there is another advantage which holds even if used only once: **It catches errors early.**

In my code the string often comes from some configuration file and I'd like to know as soon as possible if it is a valid regular expression or not. When you store just the string, it'll only fail when first used which might be much harder to test.